# How would you calculate the date of last week Friday and Saturday based on todays date and day?

Tags: php, math

I am trying to work out how to use php dates to calculate and echo the following:

-Get the date and day today ($dateToday = date("Y-m-d"); $dayToday = date("D");)
-Use the date and day today to calculate what the date was last Friday and Saturday.

For example:
If today is Tuesday the 3rd of May, we should echo out Saturday 30th of April and Friday 29th of April.
If today is Wednesday the 11th of May, we should echo out Saturday 7th of May and Friday the 6th of May.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get last Friday/Saturday by using:

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last friday"));
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last satruday"));
```

It will always return the last friday/saturday compared to today's date.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last friday")) . "," . date("D", strtotime("last friday"));
echo "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last saturday")) . "," . date("D", strtotime("last saturday"));
```